# How to make gdb send an external notification on receiving a signal?

Tags: gdb, notifications, crash-reports

I'm debug-running a daemon application in foreground mode inside gdb inside a tmux session. This daemon occasionally crashes with a SIGSEGV. Results of this crash are not immediately evident to the outside world, so it might take a while for me to discover the daemon has crashed. I would like to receive some sort of a notification immediately when a crash happens, even e-mail is fine. I've found no help from man gdb. How (if at all) is this achieved?

```
~ $ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.2 p1) 7.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've solved this one getting back to it after a while. Tip about $_exitcode in one of the answers for [Make gdb quit automatically on successful termination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740754/make-gdb-quit-automatically-on-successful-termination) put me on the path and some googling turned up [gdb hooks](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-4.18/html_chapter/gdb_toc.html#TOC147).

After some experimenting, this is what I have now for this app's **.gdbinit**. Nice thing is, I can differentiate between signals, so normal kill commands give me a normal complete exit out of the three headed monster (tmux + gdb + app), while anything out of the ordinary will drop to gdb shell, pump out an email and wait for me to tmux in to diagnose:

```
set $_exitcode = -999
set height 0
handle SIGTERM nostop print pass
handle SIGPIPE nostop
define hook-stop
    if $_exitcode != -999
        quit
    else
        shell echo | mail -s "NOTICE: app has stopped on unhandled signal" root
    end
end
echo .gdbinit: running app\n
run
```

Answer (score -1):

Something cheap and ugly:

```
while sleep 30 ; ps auxw | grep progname | grep " t "` && mail -s CRASHED username@host < /etc/hostname ; done
```

If you'd like it to only mail once ;) then there's more work to be done. But an email every 30 seconds until you kill this might be just the trick.