# How to have gdb exit if program succeeds, break if program crashes?

Tags: gdb

I seem to have some kind of multithreading bug in my code that makes it crash once every 30 runs of its test suite. The test suite is non-interactive. I want to run my test suite in gdb, and have gdb exit normally if the program exits normally, or break (and show a debugging prompt) if it crashes. This way I can let the test suite run repeatedly, go grab a cup of coffee, come back, and be presented with a nice debugging prompt. How can I do this with gdb?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a little hacky but you could do:

```
gdb -ex='set confirm on' -ex=run -ex=quit --args ./a.out
```

If a.out terminates normally, it will just drop you out of GDB. But if you crash, the program will still be active, so GDB will typically prompt if you really want to quit with an active inferior:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff72dad05 in raise (sig=...) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 15126] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n)
```

Like I said, not pretty, but it works, as long as you haven't toggled off the prompt to quit with an active process. There is probably a way to use gdb's `quit` command too: it takes a numeric argument which is the exit code for the debugging session. So maybe you can use --eval-command="quit stuff", where stuff is some GDB expression that reflects whether the inferior is running or not.

This program can be used to test it out:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    if (time(NULL) % 2) {
        raise(SIGINT);
    }
    puts("no crash");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm on OS X Snow Leopard and gdb here doesn't support --eval-command, but I'll pick your answer anyway.

Comment: I think that this won't work if you have a `set confirm off` in your `.gdbinit` file, GDB will always return ...

Comment: gdb --eval-command=run --eval-command="set confirm off" --eval-command=bt --eval-command=quit  --args ./a.out

Comment: As an alternative, consider using `gdb --return-child-result -ex r --command /dev/fd/3 3<<<$'if ! $_isvoid ($_exitcode)\nquit\nend'  --args ...` ; see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742062/151464

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to use the [Python API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Events-In-Python.html) offered by `gdb`:

```
 def exit_handler(event):
     gdb.execute("quit")
 
 gdb.events.exited.connect(exit_handler)
```

You can even do it with one line:

```
(gdb) python gdb.events.exited.connect(lambda x : gdb.execute("quit"))
```

You can also examine the return code to ensure it's the "normal" code you expected with `event.exit_code`.

You can use it in conjuction with `--eval-command` or `--command` as mentioned by @acm to register the event handler from the command line, or with a `.gdbinit` file.

Comment: Sadly this seems to make GDB dump core: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27682#c1

Comment: Note that it seems that exit_handler needs to be in a file with .py extension to be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 9):

You can also trigger a backtrace when the program crashes and let gdb exit with the return code of the child process:

```
gdb -return-child-result -ex run -ex "thread apply all bt" -ex "quit" --args myProgram -myProgramArg
```

Comment: This is not the best answer to this particular question but it helped me alot with my question! Thank you, did not know about `-return-child-result`

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named `.gdbinit` and it will be used when gdb is launched.

```
run
quit
```

Run with no options:

```
gdb --args prog arg1...
```

You are telling gdb to run and quit, but it should stop processing the file if an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Make it dump core when it crashes. If you're on linux, read the `man core` man page and also the `ulimit` builtin if you're running `bash`.

This way when it crashes you'll find a nice corefile that you can feed to gdb:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ... run program ..., gopher coffee (or reddit ;)
$ gdb progname corefile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put the following lines in your `~/.gdbinit` file, `gdb` will exit when your program exits with a status code of 0.

```
python

def exit_handler ( event ):
  if event .exit_code == 0:
    gdb .execute ( "quit" )

gdb .events .exited .connect ( exit_handler )

end
```

The above is a refinement of Kevin's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Are you not getting a core file when it crashes? Start gdb like this 'gdb -c core' and do a stack traceback.

More likely you will want to be using Valgrind.