# gdb: exit automatically only without crash

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm debugging my program with gdb. I'm able to have a non-interactive debug using the `-x` options.

```
gdb -x gdbinit ./myprogram
```

Content of `gdbinit` file:

```
handle SIGINT pass nostop noprint
handle SIGQUIT pass nostop noprint
handle SIGUSR1 pass nostop noprint
handle SIGUSR2 pass nostop noprint
run
backtrace
quit
```

The four signals aren't handled by gdb because they are needed by my program to work properly.

The `backtrace` command is useful to have a backtrace after a crash.

The `quit` command make gdb exit after the program execution, even if it has crashed.

I want to exit automatically only if the program finishes successfully. In other cases, gdb should be available to analize backtraces and other things.

**How can gdb exit ONLY if the program exits WITHOUT ERROR?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `$_exitcode` [GDB convenience variable](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html). In your gdb script above, replace:

```
run
```

with:

```
set $_exitcode = -1
run
if $_exitcode != -1 
    quit
end
```

and remove the `quit` line at the end should work. Using `-1` as an impossible value works since in POSIX only the lower 8 bits of the exit status can be used. (see `WEXITSTATUS()` in [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)).

To uses the GDB Python API to accomplish the same thing, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694502/676030).

Comment: You can avoid the line explicitly setting exitcode to -1 by changing the condition to `if ! $_isvoid ($_exitcode)`