# How to get a notification if a given process runs for longer than a specified time in Bash Linux?

Tags: bash

I all goes well, my program finishes in about N seconds:

```
./maybe_deadlock
```

But sometimes a deadlock happens randomly, and the program hangs forever.

To debug this, I want to run the program along these lines: [How to debug a rare deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770896/how-to-debug-a-rare-deadlock/27771128#27771128)

```
while true; do
  date
  gdb -ex 'set confirm on' -ex run -ex quit --args ./maybe_crash.out; 
done
```

But to make things more convenient, I want to get a notification when the N seconds have elapsed, so I don't have to keep checking the terminal to see if stdout looks stuck.

So in other words, I want to run an arbitrary command from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144924/how-to-create-a-message-box-from-the-command-line if N seconds passed and the program didn't finish.

I know about the `timeout` command from [How to kill a child process after a given timeout in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash), but I don't want to kill my process since I want to examine it on GDB afterwards.

I think I can come up with an ugly solution that puts the process on the background, sleeps, waits and touches a sentinel file, but let's see if there is a more elegant method.

This program can be test the solutions:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if (time(NULL) % 2) {
        sleep(3);
    } else {
        while (1) {
            sleep(0x7FFFFFFF);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running) on unix.stackexchange.com, you can check how long a process is running with:

```
ps -o etime= -p "$$"
```

Then you can have your script alarm if the output value is too high.