# How to make LLDB quit on success, wait on failure?

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

This is the Clang version of:

- [Make gdb quit automatically on successful termination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740754/560648)
- [How to have gdb exit if program succeeds, break if program crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8657648/560648)

---

Running my application many times, programmatically, over a large number of possible inputs, I've occasionally encountered a segmentation fault.

I'd like each test invocation to be run under `lldb` so that I can get a backtrace for further debugging. If an invocation exits without a crash, I'd like `lldb` to automatically quit so that the test harness progresses to the next iteration. This way I can set the whole thing off over lunchtime and only have the suite interrupted when something crashes.

Bonus points for having `lldb` auto-quit in all cases, but first print a backtrace if the program crashed.

I'm currently able to automate at least the initial `run` command:

```
lldb -o run -f $CMD -- $ARGS
```

Comment: C++ tag naughtily added for attention-seeking. The application _is_ C++, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having difficulty finding an online command reference but it looks like the `-batch` command line option will get you the basic "exit on success/prompt on fail" behaviour.

For a backtrace *and* auto-quit on failure I think you need the `--source-on-crash` option...

```
-K <filename>  
--source-on-crash <filename>  
    When in batch mode, tells the debugger to source this file of lldb
    commands if the target crashes.
```

So, create the command file with something like...

```
echo -e 'bt\nquit' > lldb.batch
```

and then invoke as...

```
lldb --batch -K lldb.batch -o run -f $CMD -- $ARGS
```

Comment: Pretty good! Only weakness I've seen so far is that the exit code doesn't appear to reflect that of the target. So my test harness doesn't quite know what's going on. Putting 'quit 1' in the batch file gets me partially there.

Comment: I guess the ideal solution would be, instead of `-batch`, a `--source-on-graceful-quit` with a batch file I can put `quit $exitCode` in or something

Comment: Maybe I should be using the Python bindings as a launcher

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really achieve anything more without resorting to python.  Also, can you clarify what you mean by `"Putting 'quit 1' in the batch file gets me partially there."`?  Using `quit 1` doesn't affect the exit code of `lldb` itself for me (`lldb` version 6.0.1) -- in fact, anything I type after `quit` appears to be completely ignored.

Comment: The ability to set lldb's exit value is a recent addition.  It will be in the 7 open source release.

Comment: There was a request recently for a --source-on-exit to go along with --source-on-crash.  Specific to this problem, however: batch mode is really set up to just debug one process - I'm not really sure what would happen if you started up more than one.  So it would make sense in batch mode to just automatically set lldb's exit code to that of the process that successfully exited.  Feel free to file feature requests for this and if you really want it, it should be pretty easy to hack in.

Comment: @G.M. Regarding `quit 1` admittedly I saw it discussed online and didn't actually try it yet ^_^